# Give different names to two different Django custom model managers?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm reading Django's documentation on [Custom managers and model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance) and trying to figure out if I am going to have a problem with the following code.

I have a CommonProfileInfo abstract class with a custom manager that will hold addresses for my non-business and business users.  The custom manager will contain an "add_address" method that I can use to update a user's address in the personal profile model that inherits from this abstract class:

```
# models.py
class CommonProfileInfoManager(models.Manager):

    def add_address(self, address):
        # Update user's address in PersonalProfile
        pass

class CommonProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    # ...
    address_line = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # ...

    objects = CommonProfileInfoManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I also have two model classes that contain profile info for my business and non-business users.  They also contain three GeoDjango-specific fields:

```
# models.py
class PersonalProfile(CommonProfileInfo):
    # Other personal fields...

    # GeoDjango-specific fields 
    home_point = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    current_point = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()        
    # More fields...

class BusinessProfile(CommonProfileInfo):
    # Other business-specific fields...

    # GeoDjango-specific fields 
    home_point = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    current_point = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    # More fields...
```

Have I declared these four classes correctly?  More specifically, will my GeoDjango-specific database code and queries stop working because I've declared a manager with the name "objects" in both my CommonProfileInfo and Personal- and BusinessProfile classes?  Do I need to change the "objects" declaration in the two profile classes to "default_manager = models.GeoManager" as shown in the documentation?  Should I move my GeoDjango-specific fields into the abstract class?  But if I do, won't that "objects" declaration clash with the CommonProfileInfoManager objects delcaration I already have there?  What's the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Managers` are thought of in *Django* as *Singleton* instances normally.  But, you can declare multiple `Managers` if it makes your code more maintainable than using *inheritance* for a single `Manager`.  If your wanted multiple `Managers`, you would create them like so:

```
class BusinessProfile(CommonProfileInfo):
    # model fields
    objects = CommonProfileInfoManager()
    objects_geo = GeoManager()
```

Now, you can use both `Managers` for this `Model` like so:

```
BusinessProfile.objects.custom_profile_method()

BusinessProfile.objects_geo.custom_geo_method()
```

Comment: OK.  I understand this and have implemented something like it.  However, if I go into the Python shell and do "dir(PersonalProfile)", I don't see the "add_address" method that resides in CommonProfileInfoManager.  Shouldn't I see it if PersonalProfile inherits from CommonProfileInfo?  This is what bugs me about the Django docs.  They don't provide enough detailed examples.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Check out the Djangobook: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html In the "Modifying Initial Manager QuerySet" section, it shows you how to add multiple Managers.  My other piece of advice, is Singleton objects, and inheritance are learned through knowing Python, not Django.  If you want a good book on Object Oriented Programming, Try this book.  It will give you all the tools you need: ftp://91.193.237.1/pub/docs/linux-support/programming/Python/Python%203%20Object%20Oriented%20Programming%20[Dusty%20Phillips]%20%282010%29/Python.3.Object.Oriented.Programming.Dusty.Phillips.2010.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I found that declaring "objects" and "objects_geo" variables worked.  I could also have used "default_manager" instead of "objects_geo".  Neither change affects my GeoDjango queries.